# chern character domain and codomain

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes, topological-k-theory, k-theory

I am a bit confused with the notation for the Chern character's domain and codomain.

Hatcher: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VB.pdf
defines ch: K(X) $\rightarrow$ $H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ where the RHS (codomain) should be a direct sum of even degree cohomology groups.

Is it true that the RHS (codomain) of ch can also be the Chow ring?

As for the LHS, K(X) is defined as in page 39.

In [this](https://rigtriv.wordpress.com/2009/03/22/the-chow-ring-and-chern-classes/) article
K(X) is denoted $K_1(X)$ sometimes I've seen $K_0(X)$ as well. What does $K_i(X)$ mean in this context?

Comment: What point is there in writing RHS if each time you also say codomain? 

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez just a habit.

Comment: Well, don't. A good rule to live by is: do not use any abbreviations at all here — take the time to write your questions in full words, there is absolutely no hurry.
 A second rule is that if every time you use an abbreviations you also write out it's full meaning then using the abbreviation each time is simply silly.

Comment: so anyway... I think the notation $K_1(A)$ is reserved for **algebraic** K-groups. $K(X)$ should be $K^0(X)$. Take into account Bott periodicity as well to get $K^i(X)$ in general.